# CNAME в секции NS что бы скрыть имя ориг DNS сервера

Tags: dns, bind, cname

Есть необходимость на доменах скрыть оригинальный DNS в WHOIS и подобных.
Есть панель ispmanager в настройках моего домена mydomain.ru создал записи алиасов для DNS сервера, DIG показывает:

```
mydomain.ru.        3599    IN  NS      ns1.myprovider.ru.
mydomain.ru.        3599    IN  NS      ns2.myprovider.ru.
dns1.mydomain.ru.   3599    IN  CNAME   ns1.myprovider.ru.
dns2.mydomain.ru.   3599    IN  CNAME   ns2.myprovider.ru.
```

На других моих доменах указываю везде в NS алиас DNS сервера, DIG показывает:

```
myotherdomain.ru.       3599    IN  NS  dns1.mydomain.ru
myotherdomain.ru.       3599    IN  NS  dns2.mydomain.ru
```

При такой конфигурации домены на некоторых провайдерах недоступны, почта то работает, то нет... Не могу понять из-за чего и как найти и решить проблему.
Через некоторых провайдеров пишет что А-запись не найдена, либо ошибку днс... У некоторых все работает прекрасно.

Естественно паузу выждал уже большую что бы изменения вступили в силу... По некоторым домена прошло уже полгода и поступают проблемы от юзеров что то через tele2 не робит сайт, то еще откуда то... При том что основной сайт mydomain.ru работает в этот момент, т.е. какая-то проблему в работе CNAME...

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/222641/292034

Comment: [The domain name used as the value of a NS resource record, or part of the value of a MX resource record must not be an alias](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2181#section-10.3). пытаетесь не выполнять требования rfc — получаете проблемы. всё очевидно.